# R ggplot geom_label rotate label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with labels.  I wanted the bounding background box on the label so I switched from using `geom_text` to `geom_label`.  When I was using the `geom_text` option I had my `angle = 90`.  Is there a way to do that with `geom_label`?  Or an alternative method to labeling with a background?

Here is some sample code to play with:

```
ggplot(data = iris,
       aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Petal.Length)) + geom_point(size = 10)+ 
        geom_label(data = iris,
                         aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Petal.Length, label = Species),alpha=0.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs

> Currently geom_label() does not support the check_overlap argument or the angle aesthetic.

An alternative would be to use `ggtext::geom_richtext`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  data = iris,
  aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Petal.Length)
) +
  geom_point(size = 10) +
  ggtext::geom_richtext(aes(label = Species), alpha = 0.5, angle = 90)
```

[image]